# Multiple LLVM passes with single call

Tags: llvm

In general, if I put two LLVM passes into a single command-line call, like this...

```
$(LLVM_HOME)opt -my-pass -another-pass < foo1.bc > foo2.bc
```

...is this defined to be exactly the same as running the two passes consecutively, with an additional intermediate file, like this...

```
$(LLVM_HOME)opt -my-pass < foo1.bc > foo11.bc
$(LLVM_HOME)opt -another-pass < foo11.bc > foo2.bc
```

...or are those two passes performed simultaneously in some way?

Comment: They are typically different internally. You can use `--debug-pass=Structure` to see what exactly happens. See [here](http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html#pass-statistics) for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the two passes are transformation passes, like `-simplifycfg` and `-licm`, then yes, you can think of there being an intermediary file between the two and run the commands as you suggest.

However, there also exist analysis passes, like `-aa` for alias analysis. These ones **will not** work as you describe, because they don't massage the IR, they just provide information to passes that do (like `-licm` for example).

So, `opt -aa -licm` is not equivalent to `opt -aa` followed by `opt -licm`.